# SQL Server 2014 log file very large

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transaction-log, memory-optimized-tables

I have a database with a memory optimized table and table partitions. The log file is over 300GB in one `.ldf` file, and another 40GB in another. I have tried shrinking the db, files, log

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE ('dblog' , 0)
DBCC SHRINKFILE ('dblog' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY)
```

Nothing seems to shrink the log and it's very large. Each day it gets bigger and bigger. Nothing seems to shrink it. Any advice?

- I have all the service packs already installed.
- The database is in SIMPLE recovery mode.
- I use the maintenance wizard to backup differential nightly and full on Sundays.
- `log_reuse_wait_desc` for the database is `XTP_CHECKPOINT`.
- It is definitely using the `SIMPLE` recovery model
- A manual `CHECKPOINT` did not change anything.